# Where are Library definitions located?

Tags: c++, c

Could someone say me where I can found the source file where are the definitions of the standard libraries?
For example, where is the file `string.c` that contains the definitions of the function prototyped in `string.h`? And above all, it exists?

Comment: glibc source code is at http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git

Comment: I use GNU GCC Compiler. But I'd prefer to avoid to download the whole source of my compiler (also because I think that I'd not understand a wide part of it). So, could someone link me just the implementation of `<iostream>` and `<string.h>`? It's perfect also if you use pastebin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its all in compilled state, some of maybe optimized by asm. You need find sources of your compiler to see definitions

Comment: It's not all in a compiled state.  Consider `string`

Comment: @John Dibling, agree! i mean C-functions

Answer (score 3):

For GCC, which is open source, you can download the sources for the libstdc++ library from their mirror sites [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html). Included in the download is the source for the std library. Bear in mind that different vendors will have different implementations, so the link provided is merely how the developers of GCC decided to implement the standard library

Answer (score 2):

You're probably not going to like this.

The C++ Standard does not say specifically where anything in the Standard Libraries are actually implemented.  It says where things are *declared*, but only to the degree that it names the file(s) you must `#include` in order to bring the names in.  For example, the Standard says that:

`std::string`

is a `typedef` for `basic_string<...>`, and in order to bring that `typedef` in to your program, you must `#include <string>`.  It doesn't actually say that `basic_string` or `string` are defined in `<string>` however, and it doesn't say where, on your hard drive `<string>` is even located.  In fact, it's often not in `<string>` in the real world.  In my implementation, (MSVC10) `string` is defined in a different file, `<xstring>`, and it looks like this:

```
typedef basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >
    string;
```

Useful, huh?

There's another aspect.  A lot of the stuff in the Standard Library is template stuff, like `string`, so because of the way templates work in C++ these facilities must be so-called "include libraries."  But not everything in the Standard Library is made up of templates.

Consider `sprintf`.  The Standard says that this declaration is provided by `#include <cstdio>` but that, like `string` isn't even where it's declared.  And `sprintf` isn't a template thing.  the implementation is in what's often called the CRT -- the C Runtime Library.  This is a collection of DLLs and LIBs (in MSVC10, anyway) that your program links to to run code like `sprintf`.

Now the bad news is those components that are in the CRT are generally shipped without source code.  You don't know where `sprintf` is implemented and you can't look at the source code.  You're left with little alternative in these cases except get a job with MicroSoft so you can take a look at the source code. :)

Comment: There was a source code of CRT (the whole Windows, in fact) somewhere on the Internets like 5 (or 10?) years ago. But I'd personally look at GNU, uclibc etc... Something tells me that looking at MS's sprintf implementation is useless anyway.